# android post and receive json Asyc

Tags: java, android, json, http

I am working on an android application that posts a JSON object to a server and gets one back in response. I am stuck in how to get the JSON that the server responds with back to the main thread. Below is the code that I have so far. Even after I run my background process, when I call getResponse it returns null.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, HttpResponse> {
    private JSONObject mData = null;// post data
    private HttpResponse response = null;
    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public AsyncHttpPost(JSONObject json) {
        mData = json;
    }

    public HttpResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    /**
     * background
     */
    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(mData.toString()));
            response = client.execute(post);

        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you  call the asynctask object.execute()

Answer (score 0):

U need to get data first , have u create a an adapter for it ?

when u want to get something using json, for an example title
this is how it loooks like.. you would also need to write in your main activity(depending what java use to display) to display the data.

I help this will help you. C:

```
//Declare variables
String title;


// call out the variables
public (ClasName) (String title) {

    this.title = title;
                }
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```